# How to find an item in a json array using kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an json array logged as

```
[
  {
    "Key": "key0",
    "Value": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": "key1",
    "Value": 2
  }
]
```

How do I get `Value` for `Key` with value `key0`, so `0`.

I have been using this kluge.

```
...
| extend jsonarray = parse_json(...)
| extend value = toint(case(
    jsonarray[0].Key == 'key0', jsonarray[0].Value,
    jsonarray[1].Key == 'key0', jsonarray[1].Value,
    "<out-of-range>"))
```

**Update:**

Using `mv-apply`:

```
| extend jsonarray = parse_json(...)
| mv-apply jsonarray on (
    where jsonarray.Key == 'key0'
    | project value = toint(jsonarray.Value)
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`:

```
print d = dynamic([
  {
    "Key": "key0",
    "Value": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": "key1",
    "Value": 2
  }
])
| mv-apply d on (
    where d.Key == "key0"
    | project d.Value
)
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator

Comment: How about when there are multiple rows? Each row has that json array.

Comment: generally speaking - it'd be very similar. you may want to consider providing a sample input (as done above), but also - your desired output - that may help in giving you an answer you'd be happy with