# How to find an object with key/value pair from json in Kusto

Tags: arrays, json, azure, kql

The problem I'm having is similar to this question: [How to find an item in a json array using kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370390/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-json-array-using-kusto)

I have json data that I've parsed in Kusto that contains the following block of data:

```json
{
  "wData": [
    {
      "fieldId": "my.field.A",
      "value": "Rainy"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": "my.field.B",
      "value": "Sunny"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": "tags",
      "value": "uuid:0001"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query that list and get back if the conditions of my query were met.

Example: *If `my.field.B` AND `Sunny` existed in that array as its own key/value pairing object, then it would return `true`.*

Currently, I'm trying to use mv-apply (like in the question linked at the beginning), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

**ALSO** I'm also looking to see how I can do this with multiple conditions. Essentially if I wanted to check for 'my.field.B' being paired with 'Sunny' AND that 'tags' is paired with 'uuid:0001'.

I've tried the following query but currently am running into an error where `count()` isn't allowed in the mv-apply.

The error reads: `The aggregate function 'count' is not allowed in this context.(KS144)`

```
| extend parsedData = parse_json(data)
| mv-apply parsedData on (
    extend wData = parsedData['wData']
    | where wData .fieldId == 'my.field.B' and wData .value == 'Sunny'
    | extend hasData = iff(count() > 0, true, false)
    | project hasData
```

And with the same thought process for multiple conditions, I thought I'd just make the following change to the `where` query:

```
| where (wData.fieldId == 'my.field.B' and wData.value == 'Sunny')
    and (wData.fieldId == 'tags' and wData.value == 'uuid:0001')
```

Comment: Could you share the expected result? Why do you use count() function? What value do you want to count?

Comment: The expected result is to check if the fields exist within the dataset. I'm looking for a t/f output on if all the conditions are met (even for multiple matches).

If any of the matches don't match, I'd want it to return false as an aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The aggregate function 'count' is not allowed in this context.(KS144)

`count()` function is not allowed in the `extend` operator. Thus, you need to use the `summarize` operator to count the number of rows that match the conditions. Below is the code.

**code:**

```
datatable(data: dynamic)
[
dynamic({"wData": [{"fieldId": "my.field.A","value": "Rainy"},{ "fieldId": "my.field.B","value": "Sunny"},{"fieldId": "tags","value": "uuid:0001"}]}),
]
| extend wData= data.wData
| mv-apply wData on (where (wData.fieldId == 'my.field.B' and wData.value == 'Sunny')
| summarize count_wData= count()
| extend hasData= iif(count_wData>0,True,False)
)
```

This query expands the `wData` array into separate rows using `mv-apply`, and then filters the rows based on the condition `wData.fieldId == 'my.field.B' and wData.value == 'Sunny'`. The `summarize` operator counts the number of rows that match the condition, and the `extend` operator creates a new column `hasData` that is `true` if the count is greater than 0, and `false` otherwise.

[demo1](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22OQUvEMBCF7/kVQy5NIIZ6LVRQRPCq3pZFxs2sG0iyS9vsWmv/u2la2R5MDjNv3sfMM9il/+FImFQrMH1Ab3cg2YZBeosWA788JoBXsBn43pIzzyYJ7nudlb7nip/RRZqmL2hDz0c1wL/sw5p9jWFm12iHn+0aitGaqizLWz5uR6nYlv0AfXUUDORcNUzxde6T5c83eDq5fjbhGEBcDtRQKtNAL5egrqG4pioA//bpfDn7OV8h09Y2eo+N/SaA3TGG7n05nYWQ10gHbGfH2r1YoXelemsiqSd0LUkmfwEpwgIGfQEAAA==)

**To check with multiple conditions:**

```
datatable(data: dynamic )
[
    dynamic({"wData": [{"fieldId": "my.field.A","value": "Rainy"},{ "fieldId": "my.field.B","value": "Sunny"},{"fieldId": "tags","value": "uuid:0001"}]}),
]
| extend wData= data.wData
| mv-apply wData on (where (wData.fieldId == 'my.field.B' and wData.value == 'Sunny') or (wData.fieldId == 'tags' and wData.value == 'uuid:0001')
| summarize  count_wData= count()
| extend hasData= iif(count_wData>0,True,False)
)
```

**Result:**

| **data** | **count_wData** | **hasData** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"wData":[{"fieldId":"my.field.A","value":"Rainy"},{"fieldId":"my.field.B","value":"Sunny"},{"fieldId":"tags","value":"uuid:0001"}]} | 2 | true |